# How to Write Constants Containing Multiple Values in C# Console App?

Tags: c#

Let's say I wanted to create a constant that would return exchange fees for me as `double` in C#. Here is what I would do in JavaScript:

```
var exchangeFees = {
  fidelity: .25,
  etrade: .2,
  scottTrade: .15
}
```

This way, I can import this and have it work as a sort of enum: `exchangeFees.fidelity` would get me the fee I need, and is clear. In Typescript, I would do something a bit less rational:

```
//I just realized this could just be a static class after I typed this
export class ExchangeFees {
  FIDELITY: number;
  ETRADE: number;
  SCOTTTRADE: number; 

  constructor() {
    this.FIDELITY= .25;
    this.ETRADE= .2;
    this.SCOTTTRADE = .15;

  }
}

export const exchangeFees : ExchangeFees = new ExchangeFees ();
```

This seems hacky-as-hell, but Javascript, whatchu gonna do, etc. This just seems hacky in C# though, do I just create a static class and put it in a `Constants.cs` file like so? Is there a better way?

```
public static class ExchangeFess
{
    public static double Fidelity = .25;
    public static double Etrade = .2;
    public static double ScottTrade = .15;
}
```

I read the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16045962/using-constants-or-global-variables-in-3-tier-console-application), should I put it in `AppSettings` somehow or is there no point?

I realize this is 101 question, but I am not sure I am approaching this cleanly.

Comment: Have you considered using an enum?

Comment: Yes, iirc there is an extra step to get the actual value, checking examples now.

Comment: @Sweeper If I recall correctly, you cannot have enums of type double

Comment: @YagnaPatel Enums are just `in`t as far as I can tell, and then there is the fact that getting the value requires an extra step: `(int)Exchange.Fidelity;`

Answer (score 1):

What you have is fine. An alternative would be to write:

```
public sealed class ExchangeFess
{
    public const double Fidelity = .25;
    public const double Etrade = .2;
    public const double ScottTrade = .15;
}
```

In order to have the field constant. However, that comes with drawbacks of its own, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/755685/static-readonly-vs-const).

However, your values don't really seem to be constant, and almost definitely shouldn't be baked into your code. You should use some type of configuration system. AppSettings *does* provide this functionality, but to me doesn't seem like the correct place to put it. I'd have a configuration file or database which the application reads from at start up.

Then, use your code as is, but replace the hard coded values with a (optionally cached) lookup to the configuration.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to do this:
1: You could do as you already said, and create a static class for containing constants.
2: Create the constants in your class
3: An enum wouldn't work, it only uses ints, and in your example, you use doubles
4: You could figure out some way to use an [Anonymous class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/anonymous-types).
5: This is a not-so-beautiful kind of solution: use an enum and a function that does some math and returns the proper double result.